# How to separate even and odd positions in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm learning python and trying to make some code to encrypt a string using the Playfair cipher. I have made a java file that does this, but in the interest of learning python I want to recreate the code.

The cipher requires different functions to be applied to letters at even spaces than odd spaces. For example, if we encrypted 'Hello World', **H l o o l** would all be encrypted with the even function, and **e l W r d** would all be encrypted with the odd function.

I could achieve this in java by using `for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)` and `if(i % 2 == 0)` -> even function and `else` -> odd function. But the syntax to do this in python is a bit different so I'm not sure how to do this.

I have `for x in string:`. I want to be able to separate characters that are at even and odd positions in 'string'.

Answer (score 1):

[The `enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) wraps an iterable to produce a new iterator that gives you both index and value at each iteration:

```
for i, x in enumerate(string):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        # Even stuff
    else:
        # Odd stuff
```